Network suddenly down | Activation: failed for connection 'eth0'
No updates, no new hardware, suddenly I could no longer ssh to my orangePi at 192.168.0.11.
I have tried so many things at this point. Let me try to filter what is most useful at this point.
I had a static IP configured using 'NetworkManager'.
root@orangepi3b:/home/kevin # ping -c 2 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.17 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=11.2 ms

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.167/8.177/11.187/3.010 ms

I removed the files in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/.
I flushed the routing table.
Recreated new profiles (with DHCP to test) and routes.
Tested the cables by swapping and using the tool in the switch on which it is connected.
root@orangepi3b:/home/kevin # sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        ...
 Link detected: yes

To track the issue I activated the wifi and that seems to work.
root@orangepi3b:/home/kevin # ping -c 2 -I wlan0 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) from 192.168.0.159 wlan0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.48 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=11.3 ms

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.482/7.906/11.330/3.424 ms

If I try to bring up the connection with NMCLI:
root@orangepi3b:/home/kevin # nmcli connection up eth0
Error: Connection activation failed: IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.)
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=0c351e78-2dd0-4b96-bbbd-c40400aaa6dc + NM_DEVICE=eth0' to get more details.

root@orangepi3b:/home/kevin # journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=0c351e78-2dd0-4b96-bbbd-c40400aaa6dc + NM_DEVICE=eth0
Aug 26 16:37:23 orangepi3b NetworkManager[740]: <info>  [1724690243.0188] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 26 16:37:23 orangepi3b NetworkManager[740]: <warn>  [1724690243.0245] device (eth0): Activation: failed for connection 'eth0'
Aug 26 16:37:23 orangepi3b NetworkManager[740]: <info>  [1724690243.0274] device (eth0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 26 16:37:23 orangepi3b NetworkManager[740]: <info>  [1724690243.0541] dhcp4 (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 26 16:37:23 orangepi3b NetworkManager[740]: <info>  [1724690243.0713] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'eth0' (0c351e78-2dd0-4b96-bbbd-c40400aaa6dc)
Aug 26 16:37:23 orangepi3b NetworkManager[740]: <info>  [1724690243.0728] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 26 16:37:23 orangepi3b NetworkManager[740]: <info>  [1724690243.0778] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 26 16:37:23 orangepi3b NetworkManager[740]: <info>  [1724690243.0847] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 26 16:37:23 orangepi3b NetworkManager[740]: <info>  [1724690243.0881] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)

I forgot the command but also noticed bad RX packets on eth0. Don't know if it is a cause or consequence of the problem.
My knowledge of networking doesn't go much further then this. What could be the next step to look at?
EDIT 1: Tried getting an IP from an old router, and that doesn't work either. So I can exclude issues with my actual DHCP server on the real router.
EDIT 2: I switched cables an ports on the switch. I have only 1 ethernet port on the OrangePi though.
kevin@orangepi3b:~ $ dmesg | grep -i eth
[    1.421950] psci: probing for conduit method from DT.
[    5.868920] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: IRQ eth_lpi not found
[    5.869357] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: Looking up phy-supply from device tree
[    5.869397] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: Looking up phy-supply property in node /ethernet@fe010000 failed
[    5.869434] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: no regulator found
[    5.869446] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: clock input or output? (input).
[    5.869459] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: TX delay(0x30).
[    5.869469] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: RX delay(0x10).
[    5.869490] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: integrated PHY? (no).
[    5.869574] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: clock input from PHY
[    5.869857] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: init for RGMII
[    5.870251] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: User ID: 0x30, Synopsys ID: 0x51
[    5.870267] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet:         DWMAC4/5
[    5.870281] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: DMA HW capability register supported
[    5.870290] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: RX Checksum Offload Engine supported
[    5.870298] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: TX Checksum insertion supported
[    5.870306] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: Wake-Up On Lan supported
[    5.870480] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: TSO supported
[    5.870493] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: Enable RX Mitigation via HW Watchdog Timer
[    5.870510] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: rk_get_eth_addr: use serial to generate eth mac address: 00:00:a4:07:87:ff
[    5.870519] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: rk_get_eth_addr: mac address: 00:00:a4:07:87:ff
[    5.870528] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: device MAC address 00:00:a4:07:87:ff
[    5.870538] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: TSO feature enabled
[    5.870548] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet: Using 32 bits DMA width
[    6.152102] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[    9.146764] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/clamav-freshclam.service:11: Standard output type syslog is obsolete, automatically updating to journal. Please update your unit file, and consider removing the setting altogether.
[   18.088971] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet eth0: PHY [stmmac-1:00] driver [YT8531 Gigabit Ethernet] (irq=POLL)
[   18.091343] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet eth0: No Safety Features support found
[   18.091375] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet eth0: IEEE 1588-2008 Advanced Timestamp supported
[   18.091799] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet eth0: registered PTP clock
[   18.092407] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet eth0: configuring for phy/rgmii link mode
[   18.160190] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   21.139808] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[   21.139874] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[52702.935867] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[52708.005605] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[56374.270701] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[56393.526037] rk_gmac-dwmac fe010000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[57144.079539] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
[57322.464699] device eth0 left promiscuous mode

kevin@orangepi3b:~ $ ethtool -i eth0
driver: st_gmac
version: Jan_2016
firmware-version:
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info:
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
kevin@orangepi3b:~ $ ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP  MII ]
    Supported link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes: 10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes: 10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                    100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                    1000baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    master-slave cfg: preferred slave
    master-slave status: slave
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: external
    MDI-X: Unknown
netlink error: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x0000003f (63)
            drv probe link timer ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes

EDIT 3:
kevin@orangepi3b:~ $ nmcli connection show
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
Sith                2105ac32-c7d3-46c5-a760-65fac1824667  wifi      wlan0
Wired connection 1  78e5cb19-da9c-3663-bb52-a4f2f3ab5341  ethernet  eth0
docker0             9926a32e-2db0-491e-be10-902f007e01b3  bridge    docker0
eth0                b459351a-c051-429a-adef-0b68318da4de  ethernet  --
kevin@orangepi3b:~ $ nmcli d
DEVICE         TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION
wlan0          wifi      connected               Sith
eth0           ethernet  connected               Wired connection 1
docker0        bridge    connected (externally)  docker0
p2p-dev-wlan0  wifi-p2p  disconnected            --
lo             loopback  unmanaged               --
kevin@orangepi3b:~ $ nmcli connection down Wired\ connection\ 1
Connection 'Wired connection 1' successfully deactivated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2)
kevin@orangepi3b:~ $ nmcli connection up Wired\ connection\ 1
Error: Connection activation failed: IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.)
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=78e5cb19-da9c-3663-bb52-a4f2f3ab5341 + NM_DEVICE=eth0' to get more details.



Use a different Ethernet cable and a different port.
Share the dmesg or /var/log/syslog files to observe any hardware-related issues.

dmesg | grep -i eth

# or 

sudo grep -i eth /var/log/syslog


Restart NetworkManager.

sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager


Check ETH drivers


Thank you, does that provide more insights?
